# Read xml response in unity Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, xmlhttprequest, webrequest

I got this below response from a unityWebRequest for a rest api.

What i want is that name and value of each of the object i.e inside a table.
I want to use the name as string and value as int.

How to do it ??

I saw many tutorials but all of them make use of a locally available xmldocument.

Please help me the code to do this.

Thanks in advance

```
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Property Listing For SimulationData</TITLE>
    <LINK rel='Stylesheet' href='/Thingworx/css/thingworxapi.css' type='text/css'></LINK>
    <META http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html'></META>
    <META http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache, no-store'></META>
    <META http-equiv='expires' content='-1'></META>
    <META http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache, no-store'></META>
    <META http-equiv='refresh' content='30'></META>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <IMG SRC="/Thingworx/images/ThingworxLogo.png"/>
    <BR/>
    <H1>Property Listing For SimulationData</H1>
    <TABLE>
        <TR>
            <TH>name</TH>
            <TH>value</TH>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>ActualSpeed</TD>
            <TD>0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>AirPressure</TD>
            <TD>8.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>Capacity</TD>
            <TD>1500.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>Conveyor_Speed</TD>
            <TD>75.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>CurrentTemperature</TD>
            <TD>0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>description</TD>
            <TD></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>GetEquipment</TD>
            <TD>
                <TABLE>
                    <TR>
                        <TH>Machine_Name</TH>
                    </TR>
                </TABLE>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>IdealSpeed</TD>
            <TD>1</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>isConnected</TD>
            <TD>true</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>lastConnection</TD>
            <TD>2016-09-15T15&#x3a;16&#x3a;32.111&#x2b;05&#x3a;30</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>lastConnectionError</TD>
            <TD></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>LinearSpeed</TD>
            <TD>3.5</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>Loadweight</TD>
            <TD>0.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>MilkBikiLowerRange</TD>
            <TD>98.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>MilkBikiUpperRange</TD>
            <TD>108.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>name</TD>
            <TD>SimulationData</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>NiceLowerRange</TD>
            <TD>91.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>NiceUpperRange</TD>
            <TD>99.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>NoOfRotationAgitator</TD>
            <TD>0.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>NoofRotationConveyor</TD>
            <TD>0.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>NoOfRotationsRotaryMould</TD>
            <TD>30.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>NorthEast</TD>
            <TD>34.2646815,85.7826173,0.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>NorthWest</TD>
            <TD>33.5872439,56.2797477,0.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>OvenTemperature</TD>
            <TD>50.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>PickPlace</TD>
            <TD>50.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>Power</TD>
            <TD>24.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>ScrapCount</TD>
            <TD>0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>SouthEast</TD>
            <TD>12.9036622,92.4436689,0.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>SouthWest</TD>
            <TD>39.3923528,29.8171935,0.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>tags</TD>
            <TD>Britania_POC&#x3a;Biscuit_POC&#x3b;FAndB_DemoKit&#x3a;F&amp;B_DemoKit</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>thingTemplate</TD>
            <TD>MSSQL</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>TigerLowerRange</TD>
            <TD>100.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>TigerUpperRange</TD>
            <TD>92.0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>TotalWorkingTime</TD>
            <TD>300</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>VibrationPresence</TD>
            <TD>No Vibration</TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
</BODY>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have response `string`:

you can create `XMLElement` by parsing it like this:

```
XElement response= XElement.Parse(responseString);
```

OR

You can create `XMLDocument` like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(responseString);
```

NOTE: your response string has to be a valid xml syntax.

Thought you need to use XPath expressions to extract required information.

**UPDATE:**

here is a sample code, it will give you an idea:

```
void Start()
{
    string yourActualResponse = "your actual response goes here";
    StringBuilder responseString = new StringBuilder( @"<?xml version='1.0'?>");
    responseString.AppendLine(@"<reponse>");
    responseString.AppendLine(yourActualResponse);
    responseString.AppendLine(@"</reponse>");

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(responseString.ToString());

    XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//TR/TD");
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        Debug.Log(node.InnerText);
    }
}
```

here are few links to get started:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(VS.95).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: Got this error                                                                          ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs:508)
System.IO.Path.InsecureGetFullPath (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs:357)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)

Comment: I received the response string by giving this command. xmlDoc.Load(www.downloadHandler.text);

Comment: Well the response text you posted in question is NOT xml, its HTML. And xml starts with `<?xml>` emelent and after that it can only have one root element. check this [sample file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762271(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @santhosh.r It would be a lot more easier to parse if you get actual XML response instead of HTML. I have added a sample code which works in current situation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response :)